# FSCalendar Xamarin: how to change the day label header?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, calendar

I'm starting to use FSCalendar by Wenchao for Xamarin and I'm finding problems with changing the weekdays labels, I tried using this command `calendar.CalendarWeekdayView.WeekdayLabels[1].Text = "Hello";` but with no success the labels are the same. Can anyone help me and give me the steps or example to change this ? Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific which binding library of FSCalendar are you using? `FSCalendar` by Wenchao can only applied in XCode ios project.

Comment: yes, this one: https://github.com/MarcBruins/FSCalendar-Xamarin-iOS